# Transforming XML in ISO-8859-1 to HTML

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt, encoding

I have an XML document that I'm transforming using XSL and then spitting out directly into an HTML document (all server side).

Everything works OK functionally but special characters (specifically the `©` symbol -- these are ads and many have `©` symbols) don't show up right (IE shows ? and FF shows a diamond with a ? inside).  Obviously something funky is going on encoding-wise.

The XML is in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

I tried adding `<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>` to my XSL file and `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` to my HEAD tag in the HTML.

I was thinking of running the XML through a template (XSL) that converted all special characters to HTML equivs (`©` to `&copy;`) but I was hoping I don't have to go that route.

Any ideas?

Comment: And what do they look like in the htmlsource? What processor are you running the xsl with?

Comment: In HTML Source they look the same (? in IE and <?> (that's supposed to be a diamond) in FF)

Comment: What encoding does the browser detect? Also, what is the response Content-Type header (as seen with FireBug, for example)?

Comment: Actually, that's interesting.  Encoding is detected as UTF-8.  I changed that to ISO-8859-1 and now the ? marks become ï¿½ .  So obviously something is getting lost a little higher up in the pipeline...

Header says:
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

Comment: The meta tag is *irrelevant*. The browser looks for the HTTP header, please look there!

Comment: I'm using C#, so I added Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"); but now even in FF they show up as just ? marks.  Something is getting messed up higher in the pipeline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem isn't XSLT related. You probably are missing your page return encoding (you know, like `Response.ContentEncoding`)

You can't easily convert `© to &copy;`

Comment: I'm using C#, so I added 

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

but now even in FF they show up as just ? marks

Comment: I put the explanation below -- by setting Response.ContentEncoding and seeing the response I concluded that the issue was farther up in the pipeline.  BTW: It's not that hard to convert from &copy; to &amp;copy; in the XSL file -- just use a template to search & replace.  It's just a headache and while it might work it doesn't seem like the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers (and my subsequent investigation) I realized that something was getting messed up higher up in the pipeline.  I'm retrieving the XML from a web service and so I looked up in their API and found that I can have them encode the output in UTF-8.  This works better for me anyway, so I ended up doing that and now don't have to worry about conversion etc.

Thanks for all your help!